# Custom TFS Enviroment Variable doesn't read $(Date)

Tags: tfs, environment-variables

I want to use a custom tfs variable like this:

MergedVersion: `$(BuildVersion.Major).$(BuildVersion.Minor).$(Date:yy)$(DayOfYear)$(Rev:.r)`

My problem is that `$(Date)`, `$(Rev:r)` and `$(DateOfYear)` don't work outside the BuildNumberFormat-Settings.

My result is:

> invalid version string: '1.0.$(Date:yy)$(DayOfYear)$(Rev:.r)'.

While with the buildnumberformat like shown here - works correctly:

[image]

Result `$(Build.BuildNumber)` is `MyBuildName_1.0.18004.15`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some tokens are only available in the `Build number format` section, such as `$(Date)`, `$(Rev:r)` and `$(DateOfYear)` you mentioned here. See [Build definition options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/options)

As a workaround, to use `$(Rev:r)`you can set the build number format as `$(Rev:r)`, then use the `$(Build.BuildNumber)` variable in your tasks.

To use `$(Date:yy)$(DayOfYear)`, you can set the variables via PowerShell task as ChamindaC mentioned above.

1. Add a PowserShell task in you build definition
2. Copy and paste below script and save it as `*.ps1` file
3. Check in the PS file, then run the PS file in PowerShell task

   `$time=$(Get-Date -Format 'yy')  # you can set the date format based on your requirement
   $doy = (Get-Date).DayofYear
   Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Date]$time"
   Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=DayOfYear]$doy"`

Then you can use the variables `$(Date)` and `$(DayOfYear)` in other build tasks.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use following script in a PowerShell Task in your build definition

```
$date=$(Get-Date -Format 'yy');
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Today]$date"
```

Then you can use $(Today) in your subsequent build tasks. However, usage like $(Today:yy) with format is not possible as it is supported only in build number format.

Answer (score 2):

Building on top of @ChamindaC and @Andy Li-MSFT's answers, and using Peter Groenewegen's Xpirit [Run Inline Powershell and Azure Powershell](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=petergroenewegen.PeterGroenewegen-Xpirit-Vsts-Build-InlinePowershell&targetId=ddcc2292-9d95-4d5a-9a19-7f6b2f0dfacc) build extension, I was able to retrieve the $(rev:r) from the build number:

[image: How to extract $Rev from Build.BuildNumber]

In the following MSBuild task I reference that as $(Revision).

[image: $(Revision) available in the next task]