# How do I pass information from one step in a TFS 2017 build to a later Copy Files step

Tags: environment-variables, tfsbuild

OK - I've read all about environment variables and how they can't be set and read by the same process (even this can't be read by a later step in the build):

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("Major_Build_Number", BaseReleaseNumber, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine)
```

So has anyone come up with a simple way to pass along info from one build step to another? In my first step I determine the build number (this is a fairly complex process believe it or not) and I need to pass that build number to the last build step (which is a Copy Files step) so that it can copy the build into a folder that's named with the build number. I've tried setting an environment variable, but unfortunately that can't be set and read from the same session. There's gotta be a simple way to do this. Yes I could write a PS or batch script to do it and store the value in a file or the registry, but I would prefer to use the Copy Files task and I can't figure out how to pass that value along.

I tried defining a variable in the build definition and storing the value there but I can't seem to change that value after it's set in the build definition.

BTW, this is an on-premises installation - not VSTS.

Anyone have any ideas?

**Thanks Andy** for your response. So I tried this in SetBuildNumberENVVar.ps1

```
param([Int32]$MajorBuildNumber=0,[Int32]$MinorBuildNumber=0)

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MajorBuildNumber]$MajorBuildNumber"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MinorBuildNumber]$MinorBuildNumber"
```

I then run it from the command line:

```
c:\powershell .\SetBuildNumberENVVar.ps1 23 45
```

and then try to echo the variable:

```
echo %MajorBuildNumber%
%MajorBuildNumber%
```

and as you can see it doesn't appear to work. I tried this from a C# script:

```
int.TryParse("$(MajorBuildNumber)", out mbn);
```

and mbn = 0 after this runs.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you can use the predefined variale `$(Build.BuildNumber)` to name the folder, it can be used directly in entire build process. See [Predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/variables?tabs=batch#predefined-variables) for details.

If you customed the build number variable as you said : "`I determine the build number (this is a fairly complex process believe it or not)`". Then you can pass the value with the [Logging Command](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md): `##vso[task.setvariable]value`:

1. Add a PowserShell task in you build definition
2. Copy and paste below script and save it as *.ps1 file

   `$value= "The value of the build number here"
   Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=BuildNumber]$value"`
3. Check in the PS file, then run the PS file in PowerShell task

After that, you can use the variable `$BuildNumber` directly in any tasks **behind the PowserShell task**.

You can reference my answer in another similar thread : [Custom TFS Enviroment Variable doesn't read $(Date)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48094110/custom-tfs-enviroment-variable-doesnt-read-date/48107213#48107213)

---

**UPDATE:**

You need to run the PowerShell script in TFS build process.

See below example:

I created two PS scripts, one to set the variables to pass the value, another to use the variables to create a folder named with the passed values:

PS1: PassBuildNumber

```
param([Int32]$MajorBuildNumber=0,[Int32]$MinorBuildNumber=0)

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MajorBuildNumber]$MajorBuildNumber"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MinorBuildNumber]$MinorBuildNumber"
```

PS2 : Use the variables

```
Write-Host "The Major build number is:" $env:MajorBuildNumber
Write-Host "The Minor build number is:" $env:MinorBuildNumber

$foldername = $env:MajorBuildNumber + "." + $env:MinorBuildNumber
Write-Host "foldername:" $foldername

$path = "\\myshare\DirA\$foldername"
Write-Host "path:" $path

New-Item -Path $path -ItemType directory # Create a folder
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=path]$path"  # Set path as a variable to be used in Copy Task
```

Then you can use [Copy Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/copy-files) task to copy files to that folder.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Andy. I can't format a comment so I'm going to edit my post 
 with new questions since this doesn't appear to be working. Please take a look at my new comments and let me know what I'm doing wrong if you get a chance.

Comment: @Ben_G The logging commands only available in TFS/VSTS build/release process. That means you need to run the powershell script  in TFS (local command line is not available). Just exactly follow the steps I mentioned in above  answer.

Comment: So I can't set the variables in a C# program at the start of the build? I'm leaning toward just writing the values to a file in a C# program and then reading them later in another C# program or a PowerShell script.

Comment: @Ben_G Not checked that, but the simplest way is using the Logging Command as I provided in above answer. Once the variables set, you can use the variables in the later steps with C# program or a PowerShell script during the build. Whatever here is a [guide to set environment variables with C#](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/178713-working-with-environment-variables-in-c%23/), you can have a check with that.

Comment: Hey @Andy Li-MSFT - So I got this working up until the point of the New_Item when I get the error: New-Item : Access is denied. I can run New-Item from the command-line and I even logged on as the service that TFS Build is running under and I can run it from the command line there too. Any idea what's going on? I got it to work by using New-PSDrive with -Credential passed in and then using that new mapped drive to  create the folder but that requires that I hard-code the ID and password in he script which I'd prefer not to do. I'm going to create separate post about this.

Comment: The separate post is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49562969/ps-new-item-access-is-denied-runs-fine-from-command-line-but-not-during-execut