# PS New-Item : Access is denied runs fine from command line but not during execution from TFS build

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfsbuild

I'm trying to create a script that's triggered by a TFS build that creates a new directory on a network share and then saves the location of that share in an environment variable.

Here's the (abridged) script as it originally was:

```
$NewPathForFiles = "\\NetworkShareName \" + "ProductName "+ $MajorBuildNumber 

New-Item -Path $NewPathForFiles -ItemType directory # Create the folder
```

But when I run the the script from TFS I get this error:

```
New-Item : Access is denied
```

I can run the script from the command prompt even logged in as the service account running TFS build, but from within the build I get the error.

I fixed this by mapping a drive to the share using -Credential, but that means I need to hard-code the password for the ID in the script which I'd prefer not to do:

```
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString "MyPassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("MyID",$pass)

New-PSDrive -Name P -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\MyNetworkShare" -Credential $cred

$NewPathForFiles = "p:\ProdctName " + $MajorBuildNumber 

New-Item -Path $NewPathForFiles -ItemType directory # Create the folder
```

Anyone have any ideas how I can do this without having to hard-code the PW?

Comment: Does the service account running the build process *actually* have access to the share?  It doesn't look like it.

Comment: Yes - I logged in using the service account and I can run the script or execute New_item on the share no problem.

Comment: Have you tried using the `-Force` switch?  If the directory structure doesn't exist, this will create it, and it also causes `Read-Only` to be ignored.

Comment: Nope - I hadn't thought of that as I thought New-Item would create the directory if it didn't exist (which it never will - I'm always creating a new directory). But it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @TheIncorrigible1 for the answer. Adding the -Force to the New-Item fixed the issue. Thanks!